# Filter Datatable Primefaces não funciona com p:selectCheckboxMenu

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

Fala ai pessoal!
Estou usando o filter do próprio `datatable` do `primefaces` mas não está funcionando quando uso para filtrar o `p:selectCheckboxMenu`.Quando seleciono umas das opções ele não acha nada.Usei esse exemplo e também não consegui https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml

O `datatable` junto com parte do `p:selectCheckboxMenu`

```
 <p:dataTable id="monografiasDataTable" widgetVar="monografiaTable"
            value="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.listaMonografias}" var="monografia"
            emptyMessage="Nenhuma informação a ser exibida" paginator="true"
            rows="10" paginatorPosition="bottom" selectionMode="single"
            selection="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.monografia}"
            rowKey="#{monografia.id}" filteredValue="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.listaMonografiasFiltradas}"  >

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="frm:toolbar" />

            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="frm:toolbar" />
.
.
.
<p:column filterBy="#{monografia.listaLinhaPesquisas[0].nome}" headerText="Linha de Pesquisa">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                    <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Linha de Pesquisa"
                        onchange="PF('monografiaTable').filter()"
                        converter="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.linhaPesquisaConverter}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.listaLinhaPesquisas}"/>
                    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{monografia.listaLinhaPesquisas[0].nome}" />
</p:column>
```

Comment: Passei pelo mesmo problema, havia varias colunas para pesquisa, e elas não funcionavam porque o ajax ficava fazendo pre-processamento, ai eu tive que remover as pesquisas do datatable e fazer uma barra de pesquisa separada

Comment: @WeslleyBarbosa Poderia enviar como você implementou essa consulta, pois estou ralando para fazer meu TCC e seu código me ajudaria bastante. Meu email: d.azevedo.s7@gmail.com Valeu!